# Restart a completed task

Tags: c#, task

I have a Task that run periodically in the background of my application. When I run it for the first time everything is ok and the Task run to end perfectly. But for the second time and after that whenever I use `task.Start()` it throws an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Start may not be called on a task that has completed.

I am sure that my task function ran to the end.. what should I do to run the task periodically?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to reuse the same `Task`? Can you just make a new one each time you need to run your code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Stephen Taub explains it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/14/10256832.aspx) (I can actually recommend reading more of his articles regarding Tasks)

> 1. Question: Can I call Start more than once on the same Task?
>
> No.  A Task may only transition out of the Created state once, and Start transitions a Task out of the Created state: therefore, Start may only be used once.  Any attempts to call Start on a Task not in the Created state will result in an exception.  The Start method employs synchronization to ensure that the Task object remains in a consistent state even if Start is called multiple times concurrently… only one of those calls may succeed.

.. Which is what you see as well. You can use for instance a timer and start a new Task each time.
If you need to check that only one run at a time, you can check for `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion` on the task that is currently running

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which lets you execute a callback method periodically. It's great for things that need to run hourly, repeatedly, etc. Don't forget to lock the callback method body if you need to ensure that the timer only ever runs synchronously (in case runs overlap).

Comment: Actually, Threading.Timer is threadsafe as well (it says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the bottom). My mistake

Comment: I've always been told to use `Threading.Timer` over the other one because it's a more efficient version. I haven't investigated it much past that honestly.

Comment: Well, you and me both then. I stumbled across that SOthread some time ago and have used it as a guideline since. It's just now that I saw a comment disproving the top voted answer.

Comment: Another thing, honestly, is to *never, ever* trust the MSDN's thread safety information. It's wrong far more often than it is right.