# when task's state is RanToCompletion,how to start it again?

Tags: c#, task

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp中task的状态
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Method(int i)
        {
            i =i *1000;
            Thread.Sleep(i);
            Console.WriteLine($"线程是{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}，Method中延时了{i}秒");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // Action<int> action = new Action<int>(Method);

            Task task1 = new Task(() => Method(3));
            Console.WriteLine($"task1的状态是{task1.Status.ToString()}");
            task1.Start();
            Console.WriteLine($"task1的状态是{task1.Status.ToString()}");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("主线程延迟500ms");
            Console.WriteLine($"task1的状态是{task1.Status.ToString()}");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("主线程延迟5s");
            Console.WriteLine($"task1的状态是{task1.Status.ToString()}");
            task1.Start();  //这里会报错
            Console.ReadKey();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't and you can't

Comment: if I want to run the same task,how I to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restart a completed task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791493/restart-a-completed-task)